# Bigram Counter Almost Complete Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, printing

I have an almost functional bigram counter but am stuck on two things:

a) Printing the keys and values properly as my key is a tuple

b) Looping the code to accept new lines of input

So far I've got:

```
bigrams = {}

line = input ('Line: ').split()
while len(line) > 1:                    
  bigram_key = tuple(line[0:2])       
  if bigram_key not in bigrams:      
    bigrams[bigram_key] = 1         
  else:                               
    bigrams[bigram_key] += 1         
  line = line[1:]                     

for entry in bigrams.keys():
  print (entry,":",bigrams[entry])
```

Which works on a single line of input, albeit printing extra gubbins (technical term) that I don't want:

```
Line: The Big The Big Red Fox
('Big', 'The') : 1
('Big', 'Red') : 1
('Red', 'Fox') : 1
('The', 'Big') : 2
```

What I'm after:

```
Line: The Big The Big Red Fox
Big The: 1
Big Red: 1
Red Fox: 1
The Big: 2
```

And then I need it to work with multiple lines of input!

Comment: For your first problem, research string formatting. For your second problem, learn about loops. Neither of these is an appropriate SO question - this is covered in any Python tutorial.

Comment: Well that's me told! Fair shout, I'm in my first month of Python (indeed any form of programming) so I'm sure you can forgive the faux-pas. It's all rather foggy at the moment ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first problem:

```
>>> for i in bigrams:
...     print ' '.join(i),':',bigrams[i]
... 
Big The : 1
Red Fox : 1
Big Red : 1
The Big : 2
```

For your second problem:

```
>>> bigrams={}
>>> while True:
...     print "Enter some text or enter `break` keyword to stop:"
...     line = raw_input()
...     if line.lower() == 'break': break
...     line = line.split()
...     for i,j in zip(line[:-1],line[1:]):   # Keep taking two consecutive words (bigrams) until end of line
...         bigrams.setdefault((i,j),0)
...         bigrams[(i,j)]+=1
```

Comment: I like the idea of using the text file! Not though of it like that. Although I will need to work on it as I have to take user input, not text file input. Perhaps I can get the user input to write to the file first - although the file may need flushing after each execution of the code to reset it? Thanks again though - a really useful perspective.

Comment: Oh! I thought you  have a text file. I've updated my answer as per your requirement. Hope you like it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code that I produced. Thanks for the support!

```
bigrams = {}
while True:
  line = input ('Line: ').lower().split()
  while len(line) > 1:                    
    bigram_key = tuple(line[0:2])       
    if bigram_key not in bigrams:      
      bigrams[bigram_key] = 1         
    else:                               
      bigrams[bigram_key] += 1         
    line = line[1:] 
  if line == []:
    break
for entry in bigrams:
  if bigrams[entry] > 1:
    print(' '.join(entry)+':',bigrams[entry])
```

Comment: I should add - the assignment only wanted a print-out of the bigrams with a frequency greater than one. Only just noticed that at the very end!

Answer (score 0):

**This is a much simpler answer**

```
counts = {}
line = input('Line: ')
while line:
    words = line.lower().split()
    for i in range(len(words) - 1):
      bigram = (words[i], words[i + 1])
      counts[bigram] = counts.get(bigram, 0) + 1
    line = input('Line: ')

 for bigram in counts:
   freq = counts[bigram]
   if freq > 1:
     print(' '.join(bigram) + ':', freq)
```